# XSS to get login information

Tags: javascript, php, xss

I'm messing with testing XSS using a simple html form that redirects to an insecure page with a login form (PHP server side). I'm trying to get an alert to popup on the page with the login information of the user once they hit the 'login' button. However, even after something simple like this on this initial page the redirects:

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
    <form action="localhost:8000/testpage.php" onsubmit="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="test" value="><script>alert(1)</script>">
    </form>
</body>
```

I cannot get anything to appear successfully.

Comment: You are submitting the form as soon as the page loads... So yes it will redirect.

Comment: You didn't post the PHP code of your "insecure page". The code that you've provided immediately redirects to testpage.php submiting the hidden input field, but if you do not echo out the value (in PHP by using ´echo $_POST['test'];´), the code ofcourse wont be run.

Comment: You have an extra `>` in the input markup

Comment: In the example above the script tag is inside an atttibute. You need an extra " to break out of the attribute.